# Помогите реализовать миниатюрный web сервер.

Tags: c++builder

Как правильно написать, чтобы передавать данные в браузер?
И как сделать через tcpserver. И вообще правильно ли написал.
Пишу в C++ Builder.

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
char buff[1024];
WSAData WSData;
WSAStartup(0x101,&WSData);
SOCKET server_socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

sockaddr_in local_addr;
local_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
local_addr.sin_port=80;
local_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=0;

bind(server_socket,(sockaddr *) &local_addr, sizeof(local_addr));

listen(server_socket, 0x100); // ожидание подключений
closesocket(server_socket); // закрываем сокет
}
```

Comment: Начало есть. Продолжайте.

Comment: @jack-out, после listen() нужно вызывать accept(), а потом recv(), и вероятно send().